# VS C++: Code generation of tree-like if/else structure takes very long

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, tree

I have an (admittedly large) structure of if/else conditions:

```
if ( a > 0 )
{
    if ( b > 0 )
    {
        ...
    }
}else
{
   ...
}
```

The structure is tree-like with a depth of 9 (512 nodes in total).

To make matters worse, there are 500 those that need to be compiled...

However, the code generation seems to take forever. I deactivated the optimizations (debug mode), so in my opition it shouldn't take that long to generate...

Do you have an idea how to improve the speed of the code generation?

**update:**

The code is just a Random Forest classifier that consists of several trees. So, yes, I could put this in a different structure, but the fastest code execution will be hard-coded if-conditions.

**update 2:**

I took a closer look at the output and it seems that the problem is the linking process.
Can you explain, why, or how this could be improved?

**update 3:**

This is my linker command:

```
/OUT:"C:\ProjectFolder\MyFile.exe" 
/MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT   
/PDB:"C:\ProjectFolder\\install\x64\Release\MyFile.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "ThirdPartyLibrary1.lib" "ThirsPartyLibrary2.lib" 
"kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO 
/PGD:"C:\ProjectFolder\\install\x64\Release\MyFile.pgd" 
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"C:\ProjectFolder\\build\x64\Release\MyFile.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO 
/LIBPATH:"D:\3rd\x64\lib1" /LIBPATH:"D:\3rd\x64\lib2" /TLBID:1
```

**update 4:**

Just FYI, Currently, the linking-process takes 655MB of RAM, slowly rising...

Comment: When you say code generation are you referring to compiler compilation?

Comment: When you say "code generation", do you mean "writing out the source" (I assume you didn't generate a quarter of a million nodes by hand), or do you mean "turning the source into object code"?  I suspect you mean the latter, in which case, do you have all 500 in a single file, or worse, in a single function?  If that's not the problem, I think we need more details.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve or the functionality you need to create? There has to be a better approach.

Comment: @BryanT, it's a random forest classifier, tuned for execution speed

Comment: @MartinBonner, it "turning the source into object code", and it's the linker that seems to take forever (see update above). Each tree is in a separate file / function. 500 are included into one main classifier function. Yep, it's bad, but once it runs, it's fast!

Comment: Linking 500 files doesn't seem like a lot.  1.  What does each node look like? (Do they all call the same functions, or different ones).  2.  Do you have link time optimization turned on?  3.  When you say "forever", actually how long does it take?  4.  How big is the generated executable (stripped).

Comment: @MartinBonner 1. Each node is a simple comparison function, all are comparison functions that simply compare different values on a vector. 2. See linker command above, /LTCG is enables, /GL is not enabled. 3. It's now running for 15hours........ 4. The obj. file of the 500 trees is 110MB. The .exe is 2MB.

Comment: 15 hours is a _very_ long time for any link job. Are `C:` and `D:` local drives, were they recently chkdsk'd, and is the machine running anywhere near its memory or disk capacity? Btw, what version of VC++?

Comment: I would specify `/LTCG:STATUS` to see if this in fact a code generation that is slow.

Comment: @dxiv The drives are local, the code even rests on a SSD drive

Comment: @dxiv The VS Version is 2012 (Express)

Comment: @VladFeinstein I specified this, so far, no output. It Just says "Link: Generating Code"

Comment: @S.H I still don't really get your problem... How many different final options do you have for each tree? Do you have one tree for every binary compination of you 9(?) input parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

I currently keep the if-else statements, if at a certain point I need speed by all means.

For now, I created a parameterized verison of the tree (see below).

The code then looks like this (for a tree with 16 nodes, two parameters per node):

```
// "sample" denotes the thing that I want to classify.
// nodeFunction evaluates to a true/false statement the detemines the next leaf

double decisionTree( sample )
{
    const bool isTerminalNode[ 15 ] = {false, false, true, true, false, ...};
    const double parameters[ 15 ][ 2 ] = {{1.0, 2.0}, {1.5, 7.5}, {1.7, 7.7}, ...};
    const double returnValues[ 31 ] = {-1.0, -1.0, 1.5, 3.7, ...};

    int nCurrentIdx = 0;

    while( !isTerminalNode[ nCurrentIdx ] )
    {
        if ( nodeFunction( parameters[ nCurrentIdx ], sample ) )
            nCurrentIdx = nCurrentIdx * 2 + 1; // go left
        else
            nCurrentIdx = (nCurrentIdx + 1) * 2; // go right
    }

    return returnValues[ nCurrentIdx ];
}
```

The tree structure looks like this:

```
          0
       /     \
      1       2
    /   \   /   \
   3    4  5     6
  ...  ... ... ... ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: `Do you have an idea how to improve the speed of the code generation?`

If you really need to branch your code 512 ways (and I am not sure you do), you can construct an integer value where each of the lowest 9 bits reflect the condition `(a > 0)`, `(b > 0)`, etc. Then have a switch with 512 cases, from 0 to 511.

[adding sample code]

Here is what I would do:

```
int mask(0);
if(a > 0) mask |= 0x01;
if(b > 0) mask |= 0x02;
if(c > 0) mask |= 0x04;
...
if(h > 0) mask |= 0x80;
if(i > 0) mask |= 0x100;
switch(mask)
{
case 0x01: // only (a>0) was true
  ...
break;
....
case 0x77: // all but (i>0) were true
  ...
break;
}
```

Comment: pre-computing the conditions is bad for the performance in my case

Comment: @S.H. - that I don't understand. You said: `The structure is tree-like with a depth of 9 (512 nodes in total).`, so you ARE calculating all 9 conditions...

Comment: can you give me more details? the way I understood was precomputing all 512 conditions...

Comment: @S.H - see my edit in the answer. There are only 9 conditions, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: no, unfortunately, the conditions in each node are different. So, pro-computing them results in 2^9 conditions...

Answer (score 0):

You know this already, but I'm going to say it again: you should not have a packed tree of if/else blocks to depth 9.  You should not have even one such construct, never mind 500 of them.  Whatever you are getting out of that design, you should look carefully for other ways to get it.

Are you sure these constructs are to blame?  c++ compile times can be surprising.  Are they in a header file that's included in many places?

Anyway, because this is a pretty unusual thing to be doing, your compiler is not optimized to compile it efficiently and so your compiles are slow.  If you can compile with gcc or clang instead then that *might* help, but more likely your problem has no solution as stated: if you want your compiles to go faster then you have to stop doing the weird thing you're doing, and do something else that's more like normal C++.

Comment: See above, it's a random forest classifier that was designed for execution speed.

Comment: The header file is only inluded once, the implementation is in a cpp file.

Comment: I think for *this* application, a packed tree of if/else is reasonable.  However you are right that this is at the limit of what implementations handle, and as such the aim will be correctness not speed.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.  Anyway if you're spending most of your time in the linker then the structure of the code is probably not directly to blame.  Serves me right; when something is slow, the first question should _always_ be "which part is slow exactly?"

Comment: @MartinBonner, what do you mean by "and as such the aim will be correctness not speed"?

Comment: @S.H:  When you implement a system, you want to make it work correctly for as wide a range of inputs as possible.  Having done that, you want to make it work fast for common inputs.  This is not a common input, so there will have been no attempt to make this go fast.  Would it be clearer to say "The aim of the linker+compiler authors will have been correctness not speed for these inputs"?

Comment: @MartinBonner, Now it's clear, I thought you referred to my code saying "that's not fast" :)

Comment: @MartinBonner and I agree, it's *very* weird code for a comiler and the compiler/linker - developers certainly did not optimize for that case

Answer (score 0):

Following the latest `it's the linker that seems to take forever` clarification... If that's a release/optimized build with [Whole Program Optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx) enabled, then be sure to mind the caveats at [Quick Tips On Using Whole Program Optimization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/02/24/quick-tips-on-using-whole-program-optimization/):

> - When building from the command line or via makefiles, you need to add the /LTCG switch to the link command line to tell the linker to expect to see one or more object files that were compiled with /GL. If you don’t, some build time will be wasted because the linker will have to start over when it gets to the module compiled with /GL. If you build through the IDE this is in your project configuration settings on the Linker optimization page.
> - Using /GL reduces your compile times, but your link time will increase, because work is being moved to during the link. Overall build time might increase a little, but shouldn’t increase a lot.

Comment: /LTCG is set, /GL is not set

Comment: If you are positive that /GL is not used for _any_ module, you may try to take /LTCG out entirely. And /OPT:ICF as well.